# How to pass token to verify user across html pages using node js

Tags: html, node.js

I am trying to pass a token that verifies which user is logged in across html pages. Once the user logs in a token is created which contains the user _Id. I want to use that information to get the users name and display it across html pages.

/api/user/login

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    //Validate befor use
    const { error } = loginValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send('Email is not found');

    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Invalid pasword');

    //Create and assign a token
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.Token_SECRET);
    res.header('auth-token', token);
    if (!error) res.redirect('/public/index.html');
});
```

The problem I am having is once I res.redirect back to the index, I lose the token. I want to be able to pass the token across other html pages.

I have thought of a some ways of solving this but the only way I could think of was creating another routes file so that I could use

```
router.get('/', verify, (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(req.user);
})
```

But this brings be back to the same problem that I cant pass the token to other html pages.

Comment: Is using cookies an option?

Comment: Yes using cookies is an option. Whatever works

Comment: In that case just put the token into a cookie right after `const token = ...` and then redirect them to `/public/index.html`. Then add a middleware that validates the token read from the cookie on every authed route. You can use any cookie lib for that. E.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie

Comment: Or use localStorage. The premise is to store the token value somewhere as you navigate from page to page. Cookies is just one means to that end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very common solution is to keep a token client side after the user logged in. To keep it client-side across 1 origin you can use `localStorage`.

```js
localStorage.setItem('token', 'xxxxxxaaaaaaannnnnnnnccccc.asdaasdasdasdasd');
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
```

In your login route you will obviously have to return the data, not redirect. So return the token to the user, and after the user gets the token, store it in `localStorage` and then you can do a redirect also on the client side.

```js
// server
// after successful token create
res.status(200).json({ token : token });
```

```js
// client
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

If the new page is within the same origin, the `localStorage` you set is still available.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have control of the front-end application as well, if so, I believe one way is to require the token for each request the API gets that classifies as "session logged in page", for example: get info from API, delete account...

For that, once you send in the res the token, every time the api gets a "must be logged in" request you could add a middleware used in all requests that require the token, something like this:

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const authConfig = require('./auth.json');// defining a SecretKey for the authtoken
    
    
    module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

    if (!authHeader) {
        return res.status(401).send({ error: 'No token provided' });
    }

    jwt.verify(token, authConfig.secret, (err, decoded) => { // here you verify the authtoken = key + token
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).send({ error: 'Token invalid' });
        }
        return next();
    });
}
```

As for the front-end, you will have to save locally the token provided, possibly on safe cookies, as showed in MDN documents [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie), like this:

```
document.cookie='authToken=[token]'// where token is the value saved as a string
```

And the next time the client proceeds with a request to a logged in page you send the token saved as a cookie in a authorization header, for example:

```
    myGETRequest = () => {
        const authToken = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('authToken'))
  .split('=')[1]; //all cookies are saved together in one string

        fetch(`http://yourURL`, {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "authorization": authToken, 
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        })
            .then(res => {
                res.json().then(res => console.log(res))
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
```

For more info, you can check the W3schools docs about cookies [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you attach the token to the Redirect Url? JWT usually has a limited lifetime. Someone who can access your token at some later time won't be able to use it.